# Overriding a form value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this form and what I am wanting to do when number 5 is clicked/selected how could I make that load another url and ignore whats happening within the form.

**Form:**

```
  <div id="reservation-widget-wrap">
  <div id="reservation-widget-header">Check Building Availability</div>
  <div id="reservation-widget-content">
  <form action='https://www.thebookingbutton.com.au/properties' method='get'>
  <label for='channel_code' class="caption">Select property </label>
  <select id='channel_code' name='id'> 
  <option value='1'>One</option>              
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
  <option value='4'>Four</option>
  <option value='5'>Five</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: what does *ignore whats happening within the form* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#channel_code').change(function(){

        if($('#channel_code').val() == '5'){

            window.location.href = 'Your URL';

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Why get the element by ID twice?

Comment: No reason. You could use "this" to reference the element inside the callback as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a moment and read:

[Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton (Engineer @ Google)](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

That being said, I would write it like:

Updated Html

```
<select id='channel_code' name='id' class="js-url-redirect"> 
  <option value='1'>One</option>              
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
  <option value='4' data-url-redirect="http://bing.com">Four</option>
  <option value='5' data-url-redirect="http://google.com">Five</option>
</select>
```

jQuery (javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-url-redirect').on('change', function() {
    var url = $(this).find(":selected").data("url-redirect");
    if (url && url.length > 0) {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
  });
});
```

Nice decoupled, reusable component.